# PowerShell: functional: reduce: How to initialize the reduce accumulator?

Tags: ruby, powershell, functional-programming

I want to use the functional "reduce" function to calculate things, such as the factorial of a number. e.g. The factorial of 5 is 5x4x3x2x1 = 120. In Ruby I can do it with something like:

```
# factorial1.rb

(1..5).reduce{|accumulator,element| accumulator*element}
```

In PowerShell I would do something like:

```
# factorial.ps
# ------ Install this library before using the "reduce" function
# Install-Module -Name functional

1..5 | reduce {$a*$b}
```

In both languages, the answer is 120, and the accumulator is assumed to be an integer, with an
initial value of the first element in the range.

If I redefined the factorial to have an initial value of 10, in Ruby I
would code it as

```
# factorial2.rb
# (1..5).reduce    {|accumulator,element| accumulator*element} #uninitialized accumulator
  (1..5).reduce(10){|accumulator,element| accumulator*element}
```

This yields the expected answer of 1200.

**QUESTION 1**:  How does one initialize a "reduce" accumulator in PowerShell?

In the next scenario, I want to generate a list of factorials. If
I were to code it in Ruby, I could initialize the reduce accumulator
with [1] (because 0! is 1), resulting in the following code:

```
# factorial.rb
# (1..5).reduce     {|accumulator,element| accumulator*element}  #uninitialized accumulator
  (1..5).reduce([1]){|accumulator,element| accumulator << accumulator[-1]*element}
```

The output looks something like

```
   => [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

**QUESTION 2**: How does one use an expandable array to initialize the accumulator for the
   PowerShell "reduce" function of the "functional" module?

Answer (score 1):

These questions are specific to the third party `functional` module that you downloaded assumely from the [PS Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/functional/0.0.4). Being at under 300 downloads and only a couple commits [on GitHub](https://github.com/chriskuech/functional/commits/master) this appears to be a very small project.

I took a quick look at the code base and didn't see a way to do what you were looking for, but functional programming isn't my forte. Maybe you can find what you are looking for in the [code base](https://github.com/chriskuech/functional/commits/master) and I just missed it.

Otherwise finding a different third-party module or filling a feature request might be other avenues to pursue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same reduce-object cmdlet from the functional module, getting a list of accumulated values of a factorial would be:

```
# 1..10 | %{ 1..$_ |  Reduce-Object { $a * $b } }
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
```